# Sets of Vitali's type in models of $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{GCH}$ where $V \neq L$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, real-analysis, forcing

Consider sets of Vitali's type in models of $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{GCH}$ where $V \neq L$.  Are there sets of Vitali's type in both $L$ and $V \backslash L$?  If so, is there any way one can distinguish the constructible sets of Vitali's type from the nonconstructible sets of Vitali's type?

By a *set of Vitali's type* it is meant a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing exactly one element of every equivalence class of the relation $x - y \in G$, where $G$ is some fixed countable subgroup of $( \mathbb{R} , + )$.

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by a set of Vitali type? For example, I think if $G$ is any countable subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$, then choosing representatives under the equivalence relation $x - y \in G$ will give a "Vitali set relative to $G$". The rationals are one instance.

Comment: @Avshalom:  Exactly so. What you wrote is the definition of sets of Vitali's type, relative to $G$.  As you point out, $\mathbb Q$ is the usual subgroup of $($$\mathbb R$,$+$$)$ used to define "Vitali sets" .  My question to you is, does any choice for $G$ make the set of representatives under the equivalence relation $x$$-$$y$$\in$$G$ nonmeasurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure? The phrase "sets of Vitali's type" is used as a synonym for "Vitali sets".

Comment: (With respect to $\mathbb Q$, that is....)

Comment: Let $G$ be a countable subgroup. If $x_E$ is the equivalence class of $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{g \in G}(x_E + g)$; now apply $\sigma$-additivity and translation invariance of Lebesgue measure. Will that work? The argument will apply more generally.

Comment: If so, then the countable subgroup $\langle G, \tau \rangle$, where $\tau$ is a generic real, should give rise to new Vitali sets that are not in the ground model too.

Comment: @Avshalom:  Thanks, that is very helpful.  It is my understanding that the classical Vitali argument shows that if $G$ is any subgroup of $\mathbb R$ of size less than the additivity number $add$$($$\mathscr N$$)$ and

Comment: $V$ is a selector with respect to translation by $G$ (which you indicated in your comments), selecting one element from each equivalence class, then $V$ will be nonmeasurable (at least it is my understanding now, thanks to Prof. Hamkins' answer to the mathoverflow question "Generalizing Vitali Sets to uncountable dense subgroup selectors...").  Of course $\mathscr N$ is the null ideal and the additivity number $add$$($$\mathscr N$$)$ is the largest cardinal such that the union of of fewer than $add$$($$\mathscr N$$)$ many measure zero sets still has measure zero, so as long as your subgroups

Comment: (cont.) satisfy this criterion your argument will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things to say that may answer your question.

- It is consistent with ZFC$\pm$GCH that the set of all real numbers in $L$ is countable in $V$, in which case every set of reals in $L$ has measure zero.
- It can happen that $V$ and $L$ have precisely the same sets of reals, yet $V\neq L$, because they disagree only very high up. In this case, of course there can be no set of reals in $V-L$.
- Meanwhile, if by a set of "Vitali type" you mean a set that selects one member of each equivalence class under the relation of translation by rationals, then if $L$ has such a set, then it must have all the reals (since every real differs by a rational from a member of it), and so $\mathbb{R}^V=\mathbb{R}^L$.
- Also, one can force to add a new Vitali set without adding reals, and so one can have ZFC+GCH+$V\neq L$ with Vitali sets in both $L$ and in $V-L$.

Comment: @Prof. Hamkins:  Thank you for that very nice answer--it is very helpful.  The case that interests me most is the last one, that is, the case where one forces to add a new Vitali set without adding reals so that one can have $ZFC+GCH$+$V$$\neq$$L$ with Vitali sets in both $L$ and $V-L$.  In this case, is there a way to distinguish the Vitali sets in $L$ from those in $V-L$?  I ask this question to see if it makes sense to speak of an 'evolving continuum'--that is, a continuum that grows larger to meet the needs of evolving mathematical practice.

Comment: Actually, I should really say that evolving mathematical practice might force one to construct a new Vitali set not in $L$--sorry.  As for the 'evolving continuum' one could always form new Vitali sets by adding reals so as not to violate CH, right?